# What is the expansion symbol of Face the Hydra set?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What is the expansion symbol from [the Face the Hydra set](http://magiccards.info/extra/card/face-the-hydra/hydra-head.html)?

[image: Face the Hydra Hydra Head Card]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So it is actually the Theros one reused in FTH.

Comment: Yeah, that card is from a Theros event deck.